# Is it a technical foul to throw the basketball underhand against the wall in disgust with yourself

Tags: rules, basketball, officiating

In my basketball game today, I had a very light foul called against me and out of disappointment with myself I underhand threw the ball and it hit the wall. The throw was kind of more of a toss, or medium speed underhand throw.  Imagine throwing a garbage bag into the back of a garbage truck. I didn't say anything to the refs. But I got teed up. my teammate when I got to the bench told me it's an automatic technical anytime you throw the ball against the wall. Is that true? I can't find anything like that in the rules.

Answer (score 5):

This is covered by [section A5-d3](https://official.nba.com/rule-no-12-fouls-and-penalties/#conduct) of the rules:

> 3. Overt actions indicating resentment to a call or no-call.

In your case, the referee sees this attitude as an (anger/frustration?) unsportsmanlike act.

Comment: Thank you.  I was just mad at myself but now I'm glad I just shut my mouth and subbed out of the game.